# what's the 'waging peace' meaning?

Tags: word-usage

I have known the usage of 'wage' as a verb, like 'wage a war'. But what's meaning of 'waging peace', the 'wage' here is still meaning 'engage in'?

- updated

cite from the [article](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2016/08/01/the-carters-platinum-anniversary) in the New Yorker:

> Rosalynn runs a mental-health program at the Carter Center, whose mission includes "waging peace."

Comment: The only time you're likely to encounter ***waging peace*** or similar is as a whimsical / stylised allusion to the idiomatically established ***wage war***.

Comment: @cobaltduck thanks for your mention. I update the citation.

Comment: The scare quotes warn you that it's probably a quirky / unusual / liberty-taking usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full motto of the [Carter Center](https://www.cartercenter.org/), a foundation begun by former U.S. President Jimmy Carter and his wife Rosalynn, is "Waging Peace. Fighting Disease. Building Hope."  The article quotes the first part of this motto.

In selecting these terms, the Carter Center is relying on the reader already being familiar with the common phrase "waging war," then pulling a reversal.  When you think of a group or nation that wages war, you think of them actively carrying on and being involved in activities that promote destruction, conflict, and violence.   In parallel, the Carter Center wants you to think of them as group that is actively carrying on and becoming involved in activities that promote creation, harmony, and freedom.

It is an example of a [rhetorical device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_device), and I believe one called [antithesis](http://www.literarydevices.com/antithesis/) (although I could be wrong about the exact type.)